# How to turn model into function in R

Tags: r, function, regression

Let's say, I've got myself a linear model with `lm`. Just a trivial one:

```
x = 1:10
y = 1:10
lm1 = lm(y ~ x)
```

Now I want to turn it into a function, which in this particular example would behave simply like `function(x) {x}`. How do I do that?

Well, one way would be to use predict:

```
f = function(x) { predict(lm1, newdata = data.frame( x ) ) }
```

But this looks needlessly cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you mean `f = function(x) { predict(lm1, newdata = data.frame(x) ) }` ? not sure what the `seq(x, x)` is meant to be for.

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's no reason to use seq.

Comment: But why do you see that as cumbersome?  Once written, you're off and running.  You could even expand it to `anyf<-function(x,model) predict(model,newdata=data.frame(x))` tho' I think you'll need to include an argument to force the `name` of `x` to match what the specified model's input variable names are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you would want to do this, because you'd just be writing a function to return something that's already in the R environment, but you could easily just do the following:

```
      x = 1:10
      y = 1:10
      lm1 = lm(y ~ x)

      foo <- function(x){
               return(x)
             }

      foo(lm)
    > foo(lm)

      Call:
      lm(formula = y ~ x)

      Coefficients:
      (Intercept)            x  
                0            1
```

You could build the `foo()` so that the actual call to `lm()` is included in `foo()`:

```
    foo <- function(x, y){
             return (lm(y~x))
           }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's just an example, and what he wants is to create a model that approximates a set of data, and apply that as a function to other data (new x) and outputs a new y.